# Testmethod support for record-triggered flows with scheduled paths

Tags: unit-test, visual-workflow

I thought it would be a good idea to write some Apex testmethod automation to verify the scheduled paths on a record-triggered flow. But as far as I can tell, you can't do this (as of V51)

### Am I right?

**Flow**

Updates `Foo__c.ScheduledPathUpdate__c` with current datetime when the path executes. It works fine in the UX.

[image]

### Testmethod

```
static void testFlowInterview() {
    Test.startTest();
    insert new Foo__c(Name= 'RunFlowTest');
    Test.stoptest();
    System.debug(LoggingLevel.INFO,[select id, name, ScheduledPathUpdate__c from Foo__c]);
```

### Debug log from testmethod

```
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|01p6300000GUbqz|FooAutomationTest.testFlowInterview()
DML_BEGIN|[10]|Op:Insert|Type:Foo__c|Rows:1
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Flow:01I63000001xE61
CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Flow:01I63000001xE61
CODE_UNIT_STARTED|[EXTERNAL]|Flow:01I63000001xE61
UNKNOWN|X1_HR|RunFlowTest|a1e63000000z78t|1|Hours|Thu Jun 10 21:33:11 GMT 2021
CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|Flow:01I63000001xE61
DML_END|[10]
SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[14]|Aggregations:0|SELECT id, name, ScheduledPathUpdate__c FROM Foo__c
SOQL_EXECUTE_END|[14]|Rows:1
USER_DEBUG|[14]|INFO|(Foo__c:{Id=a1e63000000z78tAAA, Name=RunFlowTest})
CODE_UNIT_FINISHED|FooAutomationTest.testFlowInterview()
```

You can see that the Flow entry conditions were evaluated as it clearly considers the +1 hour scheduled path. But no DML to update `Foo__c` occurs after `Test.stopTest();`

I'd be happy enough to verify that the scheduled paths were in fact scheduled but ...

- there are no entries in `FlowInterview` before or after `Test.stoptest();`
- Using the UX, you can see entries in `Setup | Time-Based Workflow` but this is derived from AFAIK an unqueryable SObject `WorkflowTimeQueue`

Comment: I think this [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67622/querying-time-based-workflow-queue) provides background for why this doesn't work (since, you noted it's using the same table as time-based workflow actions which have had this limitation as well). It seems there was this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873000000080eU) that was sadly closed for low activity

Comment: @KrisGoncalves - thanks for the link. Feel free to provide that as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67622/querying-time-based-workflow-queue) explains why certain declarative features are not run when running an apex test

> Apex tests are for testing Apex. They are not designed to test for declarative features.

As you noted, the scheduled path in flow is utilizing the *time-based workflow queue*. The time-based workflow queue is not queryable via Apex or the API and leaves you with no real option to try and test this. You can upvote this [idea](https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873000000080eU) that asked for the ability to test this type of scenario, but was closed with low activity.

---

In Summer '22, there's a *beta* for [No-Code Flow Testing](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_automate_flow_debug_tests.htm&type=5&release=238).

> Before you activate a record-triggered flow, you can now test it to quickly verify its expected results and identify flow run-time failures. In Flow Builder, you create, save, and run flow tests.

However, the limitations do appear to exclude scheduled paths:

> Flow tests are available only for record-triggered flows.
> **Flow tests support only flow paths that run immediately**.

---

In a [Winter '23 preview](https://unofficialsf.com/winter-23-sneak-preview-flow-builder-flow-orchestrator-flow-in-slack/), No-Code Flow Testing will be going GA and it mentions **Scheduled Paths will now be testable as well**

> No-code testing is now Generally Available, and with it, comes support for creating Scheduled Path tests and packaging compatibility.

Comment: 5 years ago, when the referred answer was written, "Apex tests are for testing Apex. They are not designed to test for declarative features." may be true. But nowadays Salesforce even force flows to have apex tests to be deployed as Active. They encourage you to test as much as possible, and they do it since 2019, so even without the No-code Flow Testing feature. Only option was Apex Test. So at least the could give the possibility of testing these flow use cases, similarly to testing Queueable jobs or @future methods, otherwise the test can not assert the logic and are not useful.

Comment: For sure, but "Salesforce even force flows to have apex tests to be deployed as Active" is not entirely true since they allow you to set the [percentage of coverage](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_flow_mgmnt_coverage.htm&type=5&release=222) which could be 0. This is not me saying they shouldn't provide a way, but to say that even though the linked answer was 5 years ago - the statement/philosophy has some truth. Hence, why they're coming out with no-code flow testing instead of adding apex testing additions.