# Testing asynchronous flow in Apex test method

Tags: apex, unit-test, visual-workflow, asynchronous, asynchronous-testing

I am somewhat vexed by this and I would like a little guidance.

I have a flow that fires on record create or update and I have written an Apex test class to test that it works as intended. I have set up this flow to run asynchronously.

When my logic is in the Run Immediately path, everything's fine and my test passes. Once I change the flow to have all my logic Run Asynchronously, however, the test no longer passes.

Based on [this](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_forcecom_ext_services_apex_unit_testing.htm&type=5&release=232), there's someway to use a mock callout the way one would test HTTP requests but I am not clear on how to approach that when trying to callout an asynchronous flow explicitly in Apex.

For clarity, here's an idea of what my Apex test class looks like. I was under the impression that `Test.stopTest()` would cause all asynchronous flows to run in sync and then process once it is done, but this does not seem to be the case:

```
@isTest
public class test_async {
    
    @testSetup 
    static void setup() {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name = 'Test';
        acc.Custom_Date_Field__c = Date.newInstance(2022,01,15);
        insert acc;            
    }
    
    @isTest
    static testMethod void testFlow() {
        
        Account acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = 'Test' LIMIT 1];
        
        Test.startTest();

        Custom_Object__c o = new Custom_Object__c(Account__c=acc.Id,Date_Field__c=Date.newInstance(2022,09,20));
        insert o;
                    
        Test.stopTest();
        
        Account updatedAccount = [SELECT Id,Custom_Date_Field__c FROM Account WHERE Id = :acc.Id LIMIT 1];
        
        System.debug('Account: '+updatedAccount);

        System.assertEquals(updatedAccount.Custom_Date_Field__c,Date.newInstance(2022,09,20));
           
        }
        
    }
```

Again, this passes when the logic in the flow runs immediately but not when it runs asynchronously. What am I missing? Is this just an Apex tests Apex situation?

Comment: I don't think this is supported

Comment: Generally you should not unit test configuration based automation. If you feel you need unit tests, it is a strong indicator this functionality should be implemented in code.

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346608/testmethod-support-for-record-triggered-flows-with-scheduled-paths from https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/346608/testmethod-support-for-record-triggered-flows-with-scheduled-paths

Answer (score 2):

In continuation to [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/400804/how-to-create-a-no-code-test-for-a-asynchronous-path-in-flow/) recent post, I've checked with the concerned Salesforce Product team and got feedback that Asynchronous paths and waits cannot currently be tested in apex tests.

I will check if the documentation can be updated to reflect this info and update this thread.Thanks!