# How to create a no-code test for a Asynchronous Path in Flow?

Tags: visual-workflow, debug, test-automation, asynchronous-testing

I'm trying to create some tests for Flows using the no-code test feature within Flow builder.

According to [this article](https://unofficialsf.com/winter-23-sneak-preview-flow-builder-flow-orchestrator-flow-in-slack/), the ability to add tests for scheduled paths was rolled out in Winter '23, but I'm having some issues using this for an Asynchronous path. I created this in a dev org with a very simple flow that updates the triggering Account record in the asynchronous path.

[image: Example Flow]

I'm able to successfully test the Async path using the Debug tool in Flow Builder.

[image: Debug tool works correctly]

However, when I convert it to test and try to click "Save", I get the following error:

> The flow test metadata for "Start" elementApiName references the
> invalid value "Test_Async-2". Check whether the scheduled path is
> available.

[image: Error when saving test]

I'm able to save this same test with no issue, if I simply change it to the "Run Immediately" path within the test. Any ideas what's going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Async path is not supported yet, but it's showing up in the UI when creating a Flow Test. The concerned Salesforce Product Development team has already filed a bug #W-12499419 to hide the async path option in the UI. There is no ETA on the fix for this yet.

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm glad it's marked as a bug because otherwise it's very confusing as to why it isn't working. Do we know when testing asynchronous paths will be supported?

Comment: @DrElyk, Happy to help! There is no ETA on when this will be supported yet.